# git svn - why can I not update to the latest revision?

Tags: git-svn

I just started to use git-svn and am having a few problems.  The one I can't seem to figure out is that whenever I setup my working copy, it stops a few revisions shy of the latest.  For instance, there are 9094 revisions in SVN and in git, I have 9080.

git svn init http://svn.repository trunk

git svn fetch

git svn info

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
   git svn clone URL projectName
```

instead and my be you should add a -s for standard layout (trunk/tags/branches).